# Find $a$ and $b$, so that $2x+y-3z = 0$ and$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{3}$ are orthogonal

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

**I am given this plane and this line**: $$2x+y-3z = 0$$ $$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{3}$$

I have to choose $a, b$ so that the line will be orthogonalto the given plane. I also have to find the point where they intersect. I am clueless, how do I go on about doing this?

Comment: vector $(-2, -1, 3)$ is orthogonal to the plane so you want $a = -2, b = -1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line in $\mathbb R^3$ is of the form $r=c+td$ where $r,c,d\in \mathbb R^3,t\in \mathbb R$.

If $r=(x,y,z),a=(a_1,a_2,a_3),b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ then the equation is written in the form

$\frac {x-a_1}{b_1}=\frac {y-a_2}{b_2}=\frac {z-a_3}{b_3}$.

Now the vector $(2,1,-3)$ is perpedicular to your plane and so you want $b$ to be parallel to $(2,1,-3)$ in order to be perpedicular to your plane.

Here you have the $b_3=3$ and thus a good choice is $-(2,1,-3)=(-2,-1,3)$. This means that

$b_1=-2,b_2=-1,b_3=3$.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful! I'm having trouble finding the intersection tho.. how can I find a point like that?